# Conditional concatenate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

Data looks like this:

```sh
  Language Files   LOC
1      C++  4009     0
2     Java     0   876
3   Python    35   200
```

I would like to add a fourth column which is as follows. Where there is a non-zero value in Files/LOC, the new column will include this value with the column name. E.g.

```sh
  Language Files   LOC                          Final
1      C++  4009     0 C++: It's Files:4009
2     Java     0   876 Java: It's LOC:876
3   Python    35   200 Python: It's Files:35, LOC:200
4        R     0     0 R: Nothing here.
```

This is pretty much the answer but is very slow on a dataframe with `dim()` 4701x158:

```
colList <- list('Files', 'LOC')
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    row <- df[i,]
    for (j in 1:length(colList)) {
        type <- colList[[j]][1]
        if (row[[type]] > 0) {
            df[i,][['Final']] <- paste(row[['Final']], '<br>', type, ': ', row[[type]], sep = '')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
cols <- names(df)[-1]
df$Final <- paste(df$Language, apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
  inds <- x > 0
  paste(cols[inds], x[inds], sep = ':', collapse = ' ')
}))

df

#  Language Files LOC                   Final
#1      C++  4009   0          C++ Files:4009
#2     Java     0 876            Java LOC:876
#3   Python    35 200 Python Files:35 LOC:200
#4        R     0   0                      R
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Language = c("C++", "Java", "Python", "R"), Files = c(4009L,
0L, 35L, 0L), LOC = c(0L, 876L, 200L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply` is not very different to your `for` loop. We could use `Reduce` (which actually also internally uses `for` loops, but different ones).

```
Final <- cbind(df[, 1], sapply(1:2, function(j) {
  paste0(" ", names(df)[j + 1], ":", df[, j + 1])
}))
Final[grep(":0", Final)] <- ""
res <- cbind(df, Final=Reduce(paste0, as.data.frame(Final)))
res
#   Language Files LOC                   Final
# 1      C++  4009   0          C++ Files:4009
# 2     Java     0 876            Java LOC:876
# 3   Python    35 200 Python Files:35 LOC:200
# 4        R     0   0                       R
```

### Benchmark

```
DF <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1e3, replace=T), ]  ## make a bigger df

reduce1 <- function() {
  Final <- cbind(DF[, 1], sapply(1:2, function(j) {
    paste0(" ", names(DF)[j + 1], ":", DF[, j + 1])
  }))
  Final[grep(":0", Final)] <- ""
  Reduce(paste0, as.data.frame(Final))
}

apply1 <- function() {
  cols <- names(DF)[-1]
  paste(DF$Language, apply(DF[-1], 1, function(x) {
    inds <- x > 0
    paste(cols[inds], x[inds], sep = ':', collapse = ' ')
  }))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(reduce1(), apply1(), control=list(warmup=100L))
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
# reduce1()  1.719615  1.751507  1.91386  1.816695  1.852541 12.01664   100  a 
#  apply1() 10.722591 10.926188 11.43564 11.029519 11.158617 18.92393   100   b
```